# What happened to Edwin Jarvis after Dark Reign?

Tags: marvel

In the events of *Dark Reign*, Jarvis  refused to join the dark Avengers and when *Dark Reign* ended  Jarvis still wasn't in the Avengers. So what happened to him? Did he retire or has he appeared among another number of Avengers ?

Comment: I know he's in the Avengers: Endless Wartime graphic novel. I think he's in the current Avengers series, but I'm not sure. I'll make this comment into an answer if I can find a reference.

Comment: I can't recall for sure, but I think he was with Hank Pym and the Mighty Avengers during the Dark Reign story line.

Comment: WEll, I don't know about Dark Reign, but it didn't go well for him in [Marvel Zombies](http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20090508214309/marveldatabase/images/0/0b/Marvel_Zombies_-_Dead_Days_Vol_1_1_page_21_Avengers_%28Earth-2149%29.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jarvis would next be seen with Hercules and his sidekick Amadeus Cho. The two would convince him to join The Mighty Avenges (a resistance force against The Dark Avengers and Norman Osborn). Cho would note that Jarvis has always been present for the Earths Mightiest Heroes.-Mighty Avengers Vol.1 Issue.21

[image]